# Percent of data pixels in a raster clipped to a buffer in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, raster

I have a raster created by unioning a set of rasters that are clipped to a buffer. I'd like to determine whether this "unioned raster" has a sufficient number of data (vs. no-data) pixels. I'm wanting to ensure my understanding of the unioned raster and how I'd compute this is correct.

The way I am doing it now is to get the width (`st_width`) and height (`st_height`) of the unioned raster, and compute the area of an ellipse of that (since the raster is not square in dimension). This in theory gives me the total number of possible pixels in the buffer that this raster represents. Then, I get the actual total count of data-pixels by doing a sum on the `st_valuecount` from that unioned raster.

Some code snippets per the above. Note, that I have many tables I'm doing this with, so while I could wrap all this up in a function, I can't since I can't dynamically substitute table names in (to my knowledge), but I imagine there's a more efficient way to get that unioned raster and use it for all these.

Get the width (and similar for height):

```
WITH myconstants (buffer) as (
    VALUES (st_transform(st_buffer(latlng_point_with_srid(latitude, longitude, upgis_utmzone_wgs84_from_latlng(latitude, longitude)), buffer_radius), 4326))
)
select st_width(st_union(st_clip(rast, buffer)))
    FROM TABLE-NAME-GOES-HERE, myconstants where st_intersects(rast, buffer);
```

Then do π x (0.5 x width) x(0.5 x height) for the area/total possible pixels.

Get the count of pixels with data:

```
WITH myconstants (buffer) as (
    VALUES (st_transform(st_buffer(latlng_point_with_srid(latitude, longitude, upgis_utmzone_wgs84_from_latlng(latitude, longitude)), buffer_radius), 4326))
)
select sum((pvc).count) from (select st_valuecount(st_union(st_clip(rast, buffer))) as pvc
    FROM TABLE-NAME-GOES-HERE, myconstants where st_intersects(rast, buffer)) as x;
```

And then I could do something like count/area as a measure of what percentage of pixels have data.

As an example with concrete numbers, I have a raster that reports a width, height of 311, 210. It also reports a count of data pixels of 50534. So:

- raster total area: 311 x 210 = 65310
- approx possible total pixels: π(156 x 105) = 51459
- percentage of data pixels: 50534 / 51449 = 98.2%

Is this correct, or what may I not be understanding or doing incorrectly, etc.?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the question a bit.

Comment: @JohnPowell let me try to rephrase here...  I've clipped a raster (or set of rasters) to a buffer, which is "round". The resulting raster has dimensions such as 311x210 (so not a perfect square). I'm presuming that's due to it being in a projected SRID? And then further, is it accurate that within that rectangular resulting raster, the corners contain "no data" because the real data is in an ellipse shaped area within the raster (given the shape is a buffer/ellipse)? Thus my approach for treating it as an ellipse to find the actual data area within the raster.